# Video quality in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediarecorder

I am using the media recorder class for recording video, I initialize the recorder with following properties,

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

But the quality of video is not as same as video I shoot over native android camera, my video recorded using media recorder is of poor quality as compared to the native one, how can I improve the video quality.

If any one knows me help me out.Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally I found the code to record high quality video in android 2.1 by setting videEncodingBitRate , AudioEncodingBitRate, AudioSamplingRate ...etc. Using this method you can set the properties for video whatever you want to provide high quality video.

For setting high quality and low quality parameter refer this page,

http://www.andgps.com/20110410/camcorderprofile-predefined-camcorder-profile-settings-for-camcorder-applications

The code i used with base version android 2.1 to produce high quality video is shown below,

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    Method[] methods = recorder.getClass().getMethods();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
    recorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);

    for (Method method: methods){
    try{
        if (method.getName().equals("setAudioChannels")){
                method.invoke(recorder, String.format("audio-param-number-of-channels=%d", 1));
        } 
        else if(method.getName().equals("setAudioEncodingBitRate")){
                method.invoke(recorder,12200);
            }
        else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoEncodingBitRate")){
            method.invoke(recorder, 3000000);
        }
        else if(method.getName().equals("setAudioSamplingRate")){
            method.invoke(recorder,8000);
        }
        else if(method.getName().equals("setVideoFrameRate")){
            method.invoke(recorder,24);
        }
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

`

Comment: I get `Method android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioChannels argument 1 has type int, got java.lang.String` on this row `method.invoke( recorder, String.format( "audio-param-number-of-channels=%d", 1 ) );`. Any idea why? Edit: I changed it to `if ( method.getName().equals( "setAudioChannels" ) ) method.invoke( recorder, 1 ); ` and it worked. Not sure if it's a good solution though. **Edit: I get `E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19` now..

Comment: Worked great on my (API 24) Samsung S6.

Answer (score 4):

use the following settings for Video Recordings:-

```
private void cameraSettings()
{
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(videoFramePerSecond);
}
```

use videoFramePerSecond = 30 and width = 1280 and height= 720.. 
This setting you can do by your own as per your requirment.

Comment: if you find this answer suitable. please accept that, so other can take advantage of this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this

`mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));`
`mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line

```
 recorder.setVideoSize(640,480);
```

Or check out the screen resolutions supported by your device and set the best one accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To enhance the video quality, you should consider setting the video size on your mediaRecorder instance to the max resolution of your device.

This snippet will do the job

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Point size = new Point();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);

mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.toString());
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10000000);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.HEVC);
mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(size.y, size.x);
int rotation =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
switch (mSensorOrientation) {
    case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
        break;
    case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
        break;
}
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```