# how can I have a high quality video recorder and audio recorder on android?

Tags: android, video, camera, video-capture, audio-capture

Hello stackoverflow friends. I am new by android and have bellow code for capturing video.
But this has low quality on phone( specially on android version 4.2 has very very low quality).
I need a video capture with higher quality but i dont know other attribute for this. how can I have a high quality video recorder ?

```
    protected void startRecording() throws IOException 
    {

     mCamera.stopPreview();
     mCamera.unlock();
     mrec = new MediaRecorder();  
     mrec.setCamera(mCamera);   
     mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
     mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
     mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
     mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
     mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
     mrec.setOutputFile(Videopath);
     mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());   
     mrec.prepare();
     isRecording=true;
     mrec.start();
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void stopRecording() 
    {

        releaseOnExit();
         mCamera = Camera.open();
         mCamera.lock();  
         surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
         surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
         surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
         surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

         Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        try {
            mCamera .setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera .startPreview();
        btnlistToggle.setEnabled(true);
    }
 //-------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
    {

         if (mCamera != null)
           {
              Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
              mCamera.setParameters(params);
              mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
              try {
                mCamera .setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } 
              catch (IOException e) 
              {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              mCamera .startPreview();

           }
           else
           {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             VideoRecorderActivity.this.finish();
           }


    }
```

Also I have a voice recorder that it has a very low quality too. what I do for upper quality voide recorder ,too?

```
public void Record() throws IOException 
        {

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(this.path); 

            try 
            {
               recorder.prepare();
            } 
            catch (IllegalStateException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try 
            {

                recorder.start();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is well discussed on stackoverflow
Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058839/how-to-set-the-mediarecorder-to-get-the-best-video-quality-effect) to learn about profiles

And this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424733/video-quality-in-android) can also be helpful. I hope it helps and happy coding! Welcome to stackoverflow community!

Comment: you helped me alot.but a question: videosize has relationship with quality?how?

Comment: Higher size means high pixel density that means details can be shown better. If that's complex is small image clear or large image? Since video is moving picture, it is the same case. Good luck!